# How do I scale indefinitely with continuous grab in Blender 2.8?

Tags: scale, mouse

In Blender versions prior to 2.8, the "continuous grab" setting would enable me to scale an object indefinitely -- that is, when the mouse wrapped around the screen during a Scale operation, the object would continue scaling from where it left off.

I am using Blender 2.82a. Now when the mouse wraps around the screen during a Scale operation, the object's scale jumps to whatever it would be if I had moved to that position *without* wrapping in from the other side.

In case that wasn't clear, here's a gif demo. I want the scaling to continue when the mouse wraps, not the discontinuities you see here:

[image: continuous grab during scale operation in 2.82a]

Comment: Hello :). It works just fine on my end. Make sure continuous grab is enabled in preferences. Other than that, perhaps some OS setting is interfering...

Comment: I have verified that continuous grab is enabled. When I disable it, the mouse simply stops against the edge of the blender window.

Comment: Well, to narrow it down, you can try a different Blender version :).

Comment: Sure enough, it's fixed in 2.83.3. Couldn't find anything in their changelog -- guess it was fixed silently. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Glad you made it work :). Just FYI - it works fine for me in 2.8-2.82